# A simple VGA controller in VHDL not working properly

Tags: fpga, vhdl, vga

I'm trying to make a VGA controller to display an image on FPGA in VHDL, so I searched and found a code in the book of Volnei A.Pedroni- Circuit Design and Simulation with VHDL in page 432 that I modified to become the code shown below. The desired behavior is that the monitor would show [the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXtqE.png) in a 256*256 square with x-position and y-position are from 20 to 275 both.

This [image to be displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXtqE.png), is a [coe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l5rkv5NdtW5KzqbeOmkZdgjpwOgR-6E/view?usp=sharing) file loaded in a ROM.

Note that the [coe](https://drive.google.com/file/d/17l5rkv5NdtW5KzqbeOmkZdgjpwOgR-6E/view?usp=sharing) file is written in Hexadecimal with MATLAB as follows :

```
memory_initialization_radix=16;
memory_initialization_vector=
38
4F
4E
3F
3F
43
40
3F
32
44
50
54
59
5A
55
53
56
57
5B
and so on.
```

My FPGA is Artix-7 Nexys-4 DDR that has a 100 MHz clock frequency.

The simulation of the whole VGA controller shows nothing wrong. But the monitor shows a very noisy square.[This is what it shows.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54KOn.jpg)

This is the VHDL code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_signed.all;

entity vga_volnei is
    GENERIC(
        Ha: INTEGER := 96; --Hpulse
        Hb: INTEGER := 144; --Hpulse+HBP
        Hc : INTEGER := 784; --Hpulse+HBP+Hactive
        Hd : INTEGER := 800; --Hpulse+HBP+Hactive+HFP
        Va : INTEGER := 2; --Vpulse
        Vb: INTEGER := 35; --Vpulse+VBP
        Vc : INTEGER := 515; --Vpulse+VBP+Vactive
        Vd : INTEGER := 525); --Vpulse+VBP+Vactive+VFP
        PORT (
            clk : IN STD_LOGIC; 
            red, green, blue : IN STD_LOGIC;
            R, G, B: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 DOWNTO 0);
            Hsync, Vsync : BUFFER STD_LOGIC
            );
end vga_volnei;
 
architecture Behavioral of vga_volnei is
    SIGNAL Hactive, Vactive, dena: STD_LOGIC;
    SIGNAL pixel_clk, pixel_clk1,pixel_clk2 : STD_LOGIC :='0';
    signal addr : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0):=(others=>'0');
    signal douta: std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
    SIGNAL line_counter: integer range 0 to Vc;
    SIGNAL column_counter : integer range 0 to Hc;
   component blk_mem_gen_0 is
    port(
     clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
     addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0);
     douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(15 DOWNTO 0)
        );
   end component;
begin
--PART 1 : CONTROL GENERATOR
U:blk_mem_gen_0 port map(clka=>pixel_clk,addra=>addr,douta=>douta);
 
 PROCESS(clk)
 begin
    if(clk'event and clk='1') then
        pixel_clk1 <= not pixel_clk1;
    end if;
end process;
 PROCESS(pixel_clk1)
begin
   if(pixel_clk1'event and pixel_clk1='1') then
       pixel_clk <= not pixel_clk;
   end if;
end process;
 PROCESS(pixel_clk)
begin
  if(pixel_clk'event and pixel_clk='1') then
      pixel_clk2 <= not pixel_clk2;
  end if;
end process;
--horizontal signals generation
process(pixel_clk)
    variable Hcount : integer range 0 to Hd;
begin
    if (pixel_clk'event and pixel_clk='1') then
        Hcount := Hcount + 1;
        if(Hcount=Ha) then
            Hsync <='1';
        elsif(Hcount=Hb) then
            Hactive<='1';
        elsif(Hcount=Hc)then
            Hactive<='0';
        elsif(Hcount>=Hd)then
            Hsync<='0';
            Hcount:=0;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
--vertical signals generation
process(Hsync)
    variable Vcount: integer range 0 to Vd;
begin 
    if(Hsync'event and Hsync='0')then
        Vcount:=Vcount+1;
        if(Vcount=Va)then
            Vsync<='1';
        elsif(Vcount=Vb)then
            Vactive<='1';
        elsif(Vcount=Vc)then
            Vactive<='0';
        elsif(Vcount>=Vd)then
            Vsync<='0';
            Vcount:=0;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
dena<=Hactive And Vactive;
--PART 2: Image generator
process(Hsync,Vsync,Vactive,dena,pixel_clk,red,green,blue)
    
begin
    if(Vsync='0')then
        line_counter<=0;
    elsif(Hsync'event and Hsync='1')then
        if(Vactive='1')then
            line_counter<= line_counter+1;
        end if;
    end if;
    if(Hsync='0')then
        column_counter<=0;
    elsif(rising_edge(pixel_clk) and Hactive='1')then
                column_counter<=column_counter +1;  
    end if;
end process;
process(Hsync,Vsync,Vactive,dena,pixel_clk2,red,green,blue)
begin
    if(dena='1')then
        if(line_counter>=20 and line_counter<=275)then
            if(column_counter>=20 and column_counter <= 275)then
                addr <= addr + 1;--increment address
            end if;
        else
            addr <= (others=>'0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
process(Hsync,Vsync,Vactive,dena,pixel_clk,red,green,blue)
begin
if(dena='1')then
        if(line_counter>=20 and line_counter<=275)then
            if(column_counter>=20 and column_counter <= 275)then
                B<=douta(3 downto 0);--RGB to be displayed
                G<=douta(3 downto 0);
                R<=douta(3 downto 0);
--               
            else
                R<=(others=>'0');--black otherwise
                G<=(others=>'0');
                B<=(others=>'0');
            end if;
        else
            R<=(others=>'0');
            G<=(others=>'0');
            B<=(others=>'0');
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Is there something wrong with data read from the ROM, or the data that are affected to the R,G and B vectors ?

If you need any additional information please feel free to ask for it.

Please try it out for yourself because I really need help and I'm stuck with it for two weeks.

Comment: Is the picture stable? What format is the picture stored, is it color, how many bits per pixel, and how many bits per pixel can be sent to monitor?

Comment: Have you tried various easier-to-see test patterns? All ones, single pixel in the middle, color bars, and so on? Have you tried the various FPGA debug features to see whether the right values are ending up in the memory?

Comment: Maybe your memory file itself is wrong.  Did you cross check it with MATLAB or some online tool whether it can generate an image like u expect from the hex data that you work upon.

Comment: thank you all for your comments, @Justme, the picture is included in the text under a hyperlink and it's colored of format jpg. I simulated the design and it showed that every pixel would get it's proper data. And as for how many bits should a pixel have or what format the coe file should be IS actually my problem, I can't decide what format should I use. As for easier to see test patterns, I didn't try them out, so I will do them thanks a lot for the advice.

Comment: You are missing the point. It is a JPG but the FPGA can't decode JPG data, so what format the stored hex dump represents and do you use the same format when outputing the data to output?

Comment: @Justme All I can tell you is that we use MATLAB to transform the jpg file to a coe file as shown above, and then we load it in a ROM to be read directly by the FPGA to be outputted on the monitor. I hope I could answer your question.

Comment: You must know how your Matlab code decodes the JPG to the output format, as obviously your VHDL must take in the same format to be able to output it correctly on the monitor.

Comment: Nobody's going to try it out without your testbench code.

Comment: Note for future readers: The OP has posted an improved version of the same question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/558693/vga-controller-simulation-works-fine-but-post-synthesis-functional-and-post-impl). So to avoid duplication of effort in both places, I'm closing this question.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is so badly formatted that it's making my eyes bleed, but the main problem is that the process that's generating your memory addresses is not actually regulated by any clock. As a result, it's generating essentially random numbers as far as the rest of the design is concerned.

This wouldn't show up in the simulation because there is a clock listed in the process sensitivity list.

Comment: There can be differences between simulated behavior and synthesized hardware behavior which leads to the now withdrawn IEEE Std 1076.6-2004 RTL Synthesis standard (followed in general by vendors today). Level sensitive sequential logic can perform as gated oscillators when provided with feedback and inversion (here `addr <= addr + 1;`). The frequency of an `addr` bit would depend on routing as well as bits to the right delay and not related to `pixel_clk`. `addr` really wants to be edge sensitive sequential logic (clocked).

Comment: @Dave so you're telling me that `addr<=addr+1` should be also under a `if(rising_edge(pixel_clk2))`statement to work properly ? because the process is already regulated by `pixel_clk2` which is derived from the principal clock.

Comment: Yes, you need the `if rising_edge(...` The fact that the clock is in the sensitivity list has no bearing on the actual synthesized design -- it only affects the simulator.